# Tag synonym proposal: [difference] --> [выбор-слова]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The somewhat popular tag [difference](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) has 46 questions, but no tag wiki.

The much more popular tag [выбор-слова](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0) (synonym: [word-choice](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)) has 388 questions, and this tag wiki excerpt:

> Questions about the difference in meaning or usage between two or more words.

This fits exactly with the question that have been tagged [difference](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference).

So, these tags should be merged:

- [difference](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) --> [выбор-слова](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)